# formatting x-axis labels with two y-axis in matplotlib (bar and line plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am plotting a bar and line plot in one figure and having problems with correctly formatting the shared x-axis tick labels. The point on the line is not in sync with the center of the bar where the tick label is drawn.

**PS: I am plotting through pandas plot function**

Example:

A. Single Bar plot (works fine)

```
libs_summary_pandas_df[['read_count']].plot(kind='bar',ax=axis,color=['#E41A1C'])
```

[image]

B. Overlaying with line plot on the secondary y-axis (**x-axis labels are messed up**)

```
libs_summary_pandas_df.total_yield.map(lambda x: x/1000000000.0).plot(kind='line',ax=axis)
```

[image]

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: shot in dark: what happens if you make your plotting calls in the reverse order? also, could you please post of a self-contained example that generates some data and demonstrates this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the [matplotlib's bar documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) which is used internally py pandas.plot :

*align  ‘edge’ (default) | ‘center’*

*For vertical bars, align = ‘edge’ aligns bars by their left edges in left, while align = ‘center’ interprets these values as the x coordinates of the bar centers.*

So adding try adding the keyword align ='center' to you first plot call and that might get aligned your x-axis.